# How to move google-chrome notifications back to the up right corner in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: upgrade, google-chrome, notification

I know that the native notification link does not work anymore but that is okay for me. But since the last update to google-chrome 49, the notifications of chrome pop up at the bottom from time to time. How can I change that? Is it a bug or a feature? I searched for it on chrome://flags but did not find any flag for that.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and am getting them in the upper right.

Comment: @FrederikFeichtmeier Are you still looking for an answer to this? Does it still apply to recent versions of Google Chrome?

Comment: No that didn't occur anymore since some months. I guess it was a bug that they patched. So this question could be removed here.

Comment: @FrederikFeichtmeier if thiis question is no longer relevant or needed since it was due to a defect, could you delete your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your Google Chrome version is seriously old. The current stable Chrome has been updated to version 60. Think about updating Google Chrome or downloading the new .deb from https://chrome.google.com.

Comment: The Chrome version probably just reflects that the question was asked back in March 2016!